# Embed Outlook.com with especific credential user generated by MS Graph access_token

Tags: node.js, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, simple-oauth2

I can login to Outlook 365 in my web with MS Graph without user action. I'm using simple-oauth2 module and oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken method to generate tokens with username/password from my database.

I'd like embed Outlook.com in my web for each user (with their credentials).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?

If your application already lets the user login with Azure Ad account, you could use the [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow. Then your web application can request a token for another resource by sending the access token of the user for the current application.

If they aren’t logged in to Azure ad already you could have a look at the [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow. Then your application will just get a token with access to all mailboxes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already using client credential flow to get a token, 
but anyway, when I call outlook.com  on-behalf-of flow is launched (and my regular user doesn't know it own password)...